# echo multiple lines (from another file) with multiple quotes/special characters into a new file?

Tags: python, linux, shell, command-line, echo

I have a python script which opens a file and reads it:

```
f= open("/file.dat", "r").read()
```

`file.dat` is a multiple lines file with quotes, spaces, new lines and special characters such as `#,&,"`

I would like to echo `f` into a new file named `t.dat`. I have tried:

```
cd= "echo \"{}\" >> t.dat".format(f)
os.system(cd)
```

which prints to the screen the file content until the "& config" which is in it and the error:
**sh: 32: Config: not found**

Tried the following as well with similar results:

```
cd= "$echo \"{}\" >> t.dat".format(f)
```

```
cd= "$echo {} >> t.dat".format(f)
```

What is the correct way to perform this?
Thank you!

Comment: Why are you using the shell for this? Just write the output file from Python.

Comment: If you really need to do this, see [`shlex.quote()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shlex.html#shlex.quote)

Comment: need to use shell since I need to run the command on another server, using aws system manager.

Comment: @Yael, `echo` is the wrong tool if you need reliability. `printf '%s\n' "something"` works more consistently than `echo "something"`.

Comment: @Yael, ...see the APPLICATION USAGE section of the [POSIX standard for `echo`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html), or the excellent [unix.se] question [Why is printf better than echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/65819/3113)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`shlex.quote()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shlex.html#shlex.quote)

```
import shlex

cd = r"printf '%s\n' {} >> t.dat".format(shlex.quote(f.read()))
```

Comment: Better to make that `printf '%s\n' {}` -- don't need `-n` disappearing, f/e, or backslash escapes being unpredictably munged depending on the target platform/implementation's level of XSI compliance.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Good idea, and used a raw string so `\n` will pass through.